Darboux chart compatible with symplectic submanifold
Suppose $(M, \omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, and let $\iota : N \hookrightarrow M$ be a symplectic submanifold. Then, are there exists a coordinate system $(U,(z, w))$ covering $N$ such that $w=0$ indicates $N$, and the symplectic form
$$
\begin{aligned}
\omega|U &= \sum \mathrm{d} z_{i,1} \wedge \mathrm{d} z_{i,2} + \sum \mathrm{d} w_{i,1} \wedge w_{i,2}\\
\iota^* \omega|U &= \sum \mathrm{d} z_{i,1} \wedge \mathrm{d} z_{i,2}. 
\end{aligned}
$$
where $z = (z_{i,1}, z_{i,2})_i$, $w = (w_{i,1}, w_{i,2})_i$.
I think it's possible.
My idea is using symplectic normal bundle on darboux chart on $N$ near $p$ and using canonical symplectic form on tubular neighborhoods on the normal bundle. However, I couldn't fill the detail.

Take an embedding chart $U_1 \subset M$ near $p$.
Choose a Darboux chart $U_2$ of $\pi_N(U_1)$ near $p$ in $U_1$.
Pullback $\omega$ from $M$ to $U_2$, then $\omega$ in $\mathrm{T}M|U_2$ could be decomposed into $\omega_1 + \omega_{2}$. $\omega_2$ is the standard symplectic form in $U_2$, and $\omega_1 | \mathrm{T}N = 0$. Hence, it's enough to see what happens for the normal bundle $\mathrm{N}_M U_2 := (\mathrm{T}U_2)^{\omega_2}$.
There is a vector bundle deformation from $(\mathrm{N}_M U_2)$ to trivial symplectic bundle, by propagating the standard symplectic coordinate in $\mathrm{N}_M U_2|p$ which makes $\omega_1|p = \omega_{\mathrm{std}}$ since $U_2$ is contractible.
Meanwhile, there is an embedding from normal bundle on $U_2$ to the original manifold $M$, by tubular neighborhood theorem.
putting all this diffeomorphism appropriately, by using relative Moser's trick up to $N$, we have a desired diffeomorphism on some tubular neighborhood of $U_2$.


You should be more specific about what you mean by coordinate system. You can never cover a closed symplectic submanifold $S$ with a Darboux chart $U$ since the symplectic form has $\omega\vert_{U}=d\theta$ meaning that $\iota^\omega=d\iota^\theta$  which cannot be.

@J.V.Gatier My intention is a coordinate chart. $U$ is an open set, and $(z, w)$ is a coordinate function(homeomorphism from euclidean space to $U$ or inverse of it). Sorry for the confusion

and that for the chart $\phi(U\cap N)={w=0}$?

Yes, $U \cap N$ is characterized like that. I didn't write the condition, but I implicitly assume that $N$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$.
